# python import variables

Tags: python, variables, import

Got 2 files:

First is called: main.py

```
import side

var = 1

side.todo()
```

Second is called: side.py

```
import main


def todo():
    print "printing variable from MAIN: %s" %(main.var)
```

I get an error, when i run main.py:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'todo'
```

In python are you not allowed to borrow and use variables, in such manner?

I have tried to search for documentation related to this, but could not find anything related to this problem.

Surely, there is an alternate way of doing this?

Comment: You have cyclic imports. See here for explanation: [Python: Circular (or cyclic) imports](http://stackoverflow.com/a/744403/222914)

Comment: Yes I understand now that cyclic loops between modules are not allowed. So is there any way to overcome this problem? besides putting everything under one source file.

Comment: @mrdigital: It's more nuanced than that. Cyclic imports between modules *are* allowed, but you have to be careful when you do it. In your case, you'll want to replace every instance `main` with `__main__` in `side.py`.

Comment: @icktoofay: That was brilliant, it works! ofcourse, it makes sense

Answer (score 2):

The problem is *not* "you can't have cyclic imports", it's that **you can't use a name before it's defined**. Move the call to `side.todo()` somewhere it won't happen as soon as the script is run, or move `main.var` into a third module.

Answer (score 0):

A fast and ugly solution is to move the import statement to where it will not be executed until it is needed in side.py

```
def todo():
    import main
    print "printing variable from MAIN: %s" %(main.var)
```

I would advice against it though. The example is contrived, but I'm sure you can find a nicer solution to your specific case.

Comment: I have tried that before on a similar problem, but it did not work.